# screen process in capitals

Tags: process, gnu-screen

I've noticed that when running `screen` the process identified with it actually shows up in capitals.

Linux Debian Wheezy.

Here an example with me ssh'in into a machine, running `screen -S test` and then running `top` there.

```
me@host:~$ ps x
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 4177 ?        S      0:00 sshd: me@pts/0
 4178 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -bash
 4260 ?        Ss     0:00 SCREEN -S test
 4261 pts/1    Ss     0:00 /bin/bash
 4813 pts/1    S+     0:00 top
 5891 pts/0    R+     0:00 ps x
me@host:~$
```

Is there any reason for this capitalisation? I don't think I've seen any other programs in capitals like this.

Screen lives on the filesystem as a lower case binary:

```
me@host:~$ which screen
/usr/bin/screen
me@host:~$ l /usr/bin/screen
-rwxr-sr-x 1 root utmp 402K Sep  4 05:07 /usr/bin/screen
me@host:~$ file /usr/bin/screen
/usr/bin/screen: setgid ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=0x035fa489e79088829da70a87252e4da70fc4a6bf, stripped
me@host:~$
```

If this is accepted behaviour or perhaps a new trend I'm not aware of?

Comment: this question *(and a related one)* is answered very neatly [here](http://serverfault.com/q/418078/257343). i found that answer by copy/pasting your question title into google. the link i followed was the second in the results list, but it probably would have been first if your question wasn't.

Comment: @mikeserv thanks for your quick reply, but the posts you mentioned do not really answer why caps is used. Why not something like 'screend' instead of a totally non-standard naming of using CAPS?

Comment: argv[0] is capitalised because that's what the developers chose to do.  This question is little different from `why is screen called "screen" and not "foobleblitz"?`  There is no reason, it's an arbitrary choice.

Comment: @cas - come on. why *not* foobleblitz?

Comment: @mikeserv don't blame me, i didn't choose 'screen`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The developers chose to do this to simplify killing stray `screen` processes.  Refer to the source repository: the change was made between versions 2.3 ([February 25, 1991](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/commit/src/screen.c?id=c9079740b6396769f5e4ed3d8f74e25c4cce6505)) and 3.1 ([September 9, 1991](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/commit/src/screen.c?id=03ca1358baa788de6060511e924ad3733f087583)), which includes these comments from [CHANGES](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/diff/src/CHANGES?id=03ca1358baa788de6060511e924ad3733f087583):

```
when the socket has been removed, send a SIGCHLD to the poor SCREEN 
process and it will try to recover. then try a 'screen -r' again.
all the socket stuff lives now in an extra file.
```

and from [README](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/screen.git/diff/src/README?id=03ca1358baa788de6060511e924ad3733f087583):

```
screen -list
screen -ls
  Show all available sockets. If there are (DEAD???) sockets, you may consider 
  removing them. If there are sockets missing, you may send a SIGCHLD to its
  process 'SCREEN' and the process will re-establish the socket. (think of 
  someone cleaning /tmp thoroughly).
```

If they had not changed the name so *thoroughly*, there was the risk of users signalling the wrong process.

Comment: Nice research. Any idea whether the idea of capitalisation of a 'parent' process was more common at the time? I can't recall ever seeing this with other processes for a similar purpose.

Comment: I only recall noticing it for `screen` (I used process renaming a couple of years before, on a `$dayjob` application).

Answer (score 0):

According to the cron manpage and this message in [Debian mail list](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2007/05/msg01097.html),

> When executing commands, any output is mailed to the owner of  the
>   crontab (or to the user named in the MAILTO environment variable in
>   the crontab, if such exists).  The children copies of  cron  running
>   these processes  have their name coerced to uppercase, as will be seen
>   in the syslog and ps output.

Comment: So does that mean that Linux filenames are not case-sensitive anymore then? That's bizarre..